# Value of the Kep always remain 0 when creating a map using for loop in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to put a `Map<String, Object>` to the `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`.

Below is the code:

```
Map<String, Object> createmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for (int j=0 ; j<jsonarr2.size(); j++ )
{
    JSONObject jsonobj2 = (JSONObject) jsonarr2.get(j);
    Iterator<String> key2 = jsonobj2.keySet().iterator();
    while (key2.hasNext()) {
        String k2 = key2.next();
        createmap.put(k2, jsonobj2.get(k2));    
    }
    System.out.println("Print J:" + j + " CREATE MAP:" + createmap);
    result.put(Integer.toString(j),createmap);
    System.out.println("result :" + result);
}
```

the For loop runs 5 times and there will be five records in createmap.
But the map `result` is using the key as 0 always and hence only the last record of the `createmap` is available in the `result` map.

Output of the print statement inside the loop:

```
Print J:0 CREATE MAP:{vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0001","timestamp":1548643752}}}}
result : {0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0001","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
Print J:1 CREATE MAP:{vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0002","timestamp":1548643752}}}}
result : {0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0002","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
Print J:2 CREATE MAP:{vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0003","timestamp":1548643752}}}}
result : {0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0003","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
Print J:3 CREATE MAP:{vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0004","timestamp":1548643752}}}}
result : {0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0004","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
Print J:4 CREATE MAP:{vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0005","timestamp":1548643752}}}}
result : {0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0005","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
```

But the final `Map` is having only

```
{0={vsan_name={"value":{"0":{"sequence":0,"value":"VSAN0005","timestamp":1548643752}}}}}
```

The key remains as 0 all the time and the value is updating to the same key.

Comment: Have you checked the content of jsonobj2?

Comment: Can you post the JSON? It seems that you have an array of length 5. And in this array you expect to find a map. I think there is only one element in your map and every time it has the same key. That could explain why you only have one element in your final map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `jsonarr2.size()` is 1 and hence, the loop runs only once (even though the nested `JSONObject` has 5 keys.

Also, you might be getting records with same key across different json objects from json array. Try moving instantiation of `createMap` inside the `for` loop, e.g.:

```
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for (int j=0 ; j<jsonarr2.size(); j++ )
{
    Map<String, Object> createmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JSONObject jsonobj2 = (JSONObject) jsonarr2.get(j);
    Iterator<String> key2 = jsonobj2.keySet().iterator();
    while (key2.hasNext()) {
        String k2 = key2.next();
        createmap.put(k2, jsonobj2.get(k2));    
    }
    System.out.println("Print J:" + j + " CREATE MAP:" + createmap);
    result.put(Integer.toString(j),createmap);
}
```

Comment: jsonarr2.size() is 5 and the loop is running 5 times. in the Print statement i am can see J value is coming correctly with different createmap value. Only in the result map i am seeing the J value remains  0 with the last record of createmap. updated the Question with the output i am seeing

Comment: Can you try changing `result` to `Map<Integer, Object> result` and see if that makes any difference?